# WP Super Cache caching broken

Tags: wordpress

I am having an ambiguous error. The path in the error is correct:

> Warning! WP Super Cache caching broken! The script advanced-cache.php
>   could not load wp-cache-phase1.php.
>
> Please edit /wp-content/advanced-cache.php
>   and make sure the path to
>   /wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase1.php
>   is correct.

What needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the constant is not defined until after the plugin loads. This error is possible if the line "require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');" is present in wp-config.php . WPCACHEHOME is probably being defined after this line, but needs to be defined above it:

```
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '<site root>/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/' ); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: My issue was somehow the WPCACHEHOME define got above the php opening element likely by upgrade or by plugin in wp-config.php.

Comment: You might then check if it's defined ("defined()") and either undefined it or print a warning and skip.

Answer (score 2):

http://wangweiqiang.net/warning-wp-super-cache-caching-broken-the-script-advanced-cache-php-could-not-load-wp-cache-phase1-php/

This worked like a charm for me...!

Comment: It's a spurious correlation. They say to move the define of WPCACHEHOME to before the define of ABSPATH, but that only works because the define of ABSPATH happens to be before the require_once of the wp_settings.php script, which is where the constant is actually missing, which is [implied] by the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue, U should check that the paths mantioned in the error notice have 777 permisions, BUT, my advice on this issue is simply to NOT use this plugin, I had it installed on some of my site, and almost in all of them it caused errors on diffrent elements on my site.
I'm not saying that using this plugin will cause problems for sure, but this plugin is known as problematic, and for my opinion it doesn't justify itself.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this in your wp-config.php file

```
define('WPCACHEHOME', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/');
```

before

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Comment: The order of defines does not matter if one does not depend on the other. The issue here is that the define must be present prior to the require (wherein the constant is referenced).